# Toshiba P775-S7215 with a broken wireless button?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, toshiba-laptop

I'm troubleshooting a wireless connectivity problem on a Toshiba P775-S7215.  The wireless seems to be stuck "Off".  Pressing the wireless button (located to the right of the power button) causes it to beep and light up, but then it seems to turn itself off (light goes out).  Holding FN-F8 causes a window to pop up that claims "the wireless communication switch is off".  Disabling "eco mode" via the Toshiba eco Utility in the system tray causes the eco light (green light between the power button and the wireless button) to go out and the wireless button to light up, but everything still claims the hardware radio switch is still off (including the Intel My WiFi utility in the system tray).  Pressing the wireless button in this configuration causes a beep and the light goes off briefly before coming back on.

The owner claims no configuration changes have been made recently and the problem started occurring today after a cold boot.

Going back to a system restore point several days ago failed to resolve the problem.  The last Windows Update activity was before this restore point.

The operating system is Windows 7 home premium, as delivered, with all the Toshiba pre-installs.  The wireless card is a Centrino Wireless-N 6150.

I've looked all over the case for another switch and there isn't one.

Any suggestions other than taping a pin on the wireless card until it gets sent in for warranty service?

**UPDATE**

There was no "wireless communication switch" option in the installed HWSetup, but TBSWireless was present and did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [seems](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletinDetail.jsp?pf=true&soid=2364520) the "wireless communication switch" on some models is implemented as a software switch.  Check to see if there is a wireless switch option in the installed HWSetup utility.  If not, [look](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Networking-Wi-Fi/Unable-to-turn-on-the-wireless-communication-switch-Please-HELP/td-p/213128) for TBSWireless:

1. Navigate to C:-->Program Files-->Toshiba-->TBS
2. Double Click TBSWireless

Comment: This answer (TBSWireless) worked perfectly on a Toshiba Satellite P775-S7100 running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction here would be to reseat the wireless card. If that doesn't work swap it with another one. It really seems as though it is a card/slot issue, not necessarily a software or driver problem.

Comment: It looks like, from googled pictures anyway, that the palm rest is one solid piece from top to bottom, I think it might come off without taking the screen assembly completely off. Unfortunately the keyboard doesn't just flip up like on older style laptops. I might have access to one of these and might be able to take a closer look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I have a A665 it looks like, not an A775, however, very similar body styles, and the keyboard appears to lift out without tearing it completely down, my assumption would be a few screws out of the bottom that line up with the keyboard and it will come off.